# download attribute in `a` tag is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have used download attribute in my code using jquery. it was not working

```
data = /images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg
a = $('<a>').attr('href', data).attr('download', 'image.jpg').attr('id', 'sample').attr('target', '_blank').appendTo('body')
a[0].click()
a.remove()
```

Rest of the atrributes are working fine. But only download attribute is not working.

[image]

why I am getting this?

Comment: use as `attr('download', true)`, set file path in `href` so download will work.

Comment: this is not working

Comment: you dont need to use `attr` just append plain html to body.

Comment: I have added screenshot above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The download attribute is not supported in Edge version 12, IE, Safari
>   10 (and earlier), or Opera version 12 (and earlier).

One reason why it does not work is because your file path is incorrect.
Check if your file does exist.
This is not a correct syntax

```
attr('download', 'image.jpg');
```

You should do this instead:

```
attr("download", true);
```

Here is a working code:
I used a sample image from w3schools

```js
var data = 'https://www.w3schools.com/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg';

var $a = $('<a />').appendTo('body');
$a.attr('id', 'sample');
$a.attr('href', data);
$a.attr("download", true);
$a.attr('target', '_blank');
$a[0].click();
$a.remove();
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: I have added screenshot above

Comment: what are we supposed to see running your snippet?

Comment: If you run this code in your browser it should download a file :P

Comment: No even it does not showing the above screenshot. It simply opens that image in new tab

Comment: @Priyanga added a gif to my answer, what browser are u using/targeting?

Comment: I have tested this in chrome and Firefox

Comment: @Priyanga you see my gif is working right? is that what u want?

Comment: Found that it does not works for my url in w3schools editor and does not works for any url in my own code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198529/discussion-between-jbadminton-and-priyanga).

Answer (score 2):

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) has a note about this attribute.

> If Content-Disposition: is set to inline, Firefox prioritizes Content-Disposition, like the filename case, while Chrome prioritizes the download attribute

It depends on

- how the content is served, i.e. what is `Content-Disposition`
- how the browser handles it

Answer (score -2):

```
a = $('<a>').attr('href', data).attr('download', 'image') ...
                                                     ^^^
```

Do not specify the extension of the file